# Magnet file to .torrent as hyperlink is to .html?

Tags: p2p, bittorrent, utorrent, magnet-uri

I have my own site where I host my own unique content.

I am adding the option to download my unique content via torrents.

I understand that you need a .torrent file to download data over a P2P network, but people are talking about completely switching to magnet links and not needing .torrents..???

As far as I'm concerned, Magnet links still point to .torrent files and you need the .torrent to start downloading?

Is a Magnet link similar to a http link, as even though it's not a file, you still end up downloading the .torrent file (.html file) once you click on it?

I.E. I cannot create a P2P network for my site only using Magnet links, I still need to create the .torrent file, right?

Thanks,

Comment: I found a better answer to pretty much finalize my understanding.

I'll post a link to a public forum on uTorrent.

[http://forum.utorrent.com/viewtopic.php?id=64562](http://forum.utorrent.com/viewtopic.php?id=64562)

Comment: The simple thing is this: If you are trying to broadcast your own content, create the .torrent file. If you are trying to broadcast someone else's content, use a magnet link whose hash value links to the .torrent's hash value.

Answer (score 0):

The comparable concepts are URL vs. URN, i.e. "physical" location vs. content ID.